# NGINX cache only images, css, fonts in a specific directory

Tags: nginx

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ico)$ {
     expires 15d;
     add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
}
```

I have the code above which is supposed to cache these files for 15 days.  how do I fix it so that only the files coming from /js, /css, /img will get cached instead of all?

Answer (score 0):

Change the location rule to:

```
location ~ ^/(js|css|img)/*\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ico)$ {
     expires 15d;
     add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
}
```

That should work

Comment: did not seem to work.  for now  i am sticking with the original code.